# Is KVM Over IP the same as an IPMI?

Tags: security, kvm-switch, ipmi

The reason I ask is because my provider gives me an IP that I go to and I can login and access  my server via a web interface on a public IP.

Recently, there has been a lot of hacks via exploits to IPMI devices.

Is this an issue I should worry about or do I need to have my provider take down these KvM IPs?

Comment: Q: Is KVM Over IP the same as an IPMI? A: No it is not.

Comment: But some vendors refer to IPMI devices as iKVM devices. see here for one example: http://www.asus.com/Commercial_Servers_Workstations/ASMB6iKVM/ Also note that the current exploits are against specific implementations and downversion protocols, so read up here: http://threatpost.com/ipmi-protocol-bmc-vulnerabilities-expose-thousands-of-servers-to-attack . Either way, this kind of remote management is a very dangerous service, and should only be used in the strictest of configurations if public facing.